# Easiest way to find GMT offsets where local time is between certain hours?

Tags: php

If it's 2am in London, how can I find the GMT offsets in seconds where the local time is between 7am and 7pm?

I have database records with a GMT offset column (-3600, -14400, 28000 etc) . I'd like to be able to select by those with offsets falling roughly within local daytime hours. Right now, which of these offsets are in daytime hours? I'm totally at a loss for how to approach this.

Comment: Hint: How would you go about finding the time zone that currently has 7am?

Comment: Sounds like that would go a long way to answering my question, except I want to be able to query by something like "select * from table where offset >= 3600 and offset <= 46800" so I need to know the offset from GMT that is currently between 7am and 7pm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier that in looks. If you have the time passed since UTC midnight, in seconds, like here

```
$gmtSecondsSinceMidnight = (gmmktime() - gmmktime(0,0,0));
```

then timezones should be within `60*60*7` and `60*60*19` seconds distance from that, relative to GMT. 19 is 7pm in 24h notation.

```
$remoteTZStartZ1 = 7*$hour - $gmtSecondsSinceMidnight;
$remoteTZEndZ1 = 19*$hour - $gmtSecondsSinceMidnight;
```

This would suffice to formulate a query like

```
echo "SELECT name FROM timezones WHERE 
    (offsetSeconds > $remoteTZStartZ1 AND offsetSeconds < $remoteTZEndZ1);";
```

However, you'll need to construct two additional brackets if the `remoteTZ` variables go beyond a 12h offset. Otherwise you might try to select timezones with an offset greater than 12h or below -12h. To make it "wrap around", copy the offsets to ±24h:

```
$remoteTZStartZ2 = $remoteTZStartZ1 - 24*$hour;
$remoteTZEndZ2 = $remoteTZEndZ1 - 24*$hour;
$remoteTZStartZ3 = $remoteTZStartZ1 + 24*$hour;
$remoteTZEndZ3 = $remoteTZEndZ1 + 24*$hour;
```

and use a query like this

```
echo "SELECT name FROM timezones WHERE 
    (offsetSeconds > $remoteTZStartZ1 AND offsetSeconds < $remoteTZEndZ1) OR 
    (offsetSeconds > $remoteTZStartZ2 AND offsetSeconds < $remoteTZEndZ2) OR 
    (offsetSeconds > $remoteTZStartZ3 AND offsetSeconds < $remoteTZEndZ3);";
```

Comment: @Fo. I fixed a typo after I actually tried it. It's kinda late already over here.

Comment: As I write this it is 9:40pm in London. that means the query (first one) should be "SELECT name FROM timezones WHERE offsetSeconds < -9600 AND offsetSeconds > -52800;" but I'm getting "SELECT name FROM timezones WHERE offsetSeconds < 43200 AND offsetSeconds > 0;"

Comment: I checked it again. London currently GMT+1 currently, because of summer time. Would you like to [discuss this in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30228/time-in-london)?

Comment: It's late where you are, there's no urgency, thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 1):

likeitlikeit's answer helped to refine my efforts, the only thing missing really was anchoring in an actual timestamp. I crudely solved the problem this way, though this could be vastly improved:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$currentTimestamp = time();
$startHour = strtotime("7am");
$endHour = $startHour+50400; //9pm
$start = ($startHour>$currentTimestamp) ? ($startHour - $currentTimestamp) : -1 * abs($currentTimestamp - $startHour);
$end = ($endHour>$currentTimestamp) ? ($endHour - $currentTimestamp) : -1 * abs($currentTimestamp - $endHour);
```

Comment: I updated [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16638375/1553481) to match your output. Sorry I didn't make it anymore yesterday; why don't you have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has this function for version 5.2+ [DateTimeZone::getOffset](http://br.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php)

Comment: I already have the offsets, as stated in the question. I want to know if the offset is located in a region that is currently in daylight hours based on a rough range of 7am to 7pm.

Comment: Sorry... I think this is what you're looking for: http://br.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php. The idea is: create the date from your current timezone, set the timezone of that object to an object created with you offset, the time will change automatically, then you verify if it is in your interval...

Comment: This function will allow you to create a timezone from your offsets: http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-name-from-abbr.php